# Cant get values into View Mvc5 Identity

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a controller in Accouncontroller where I get all my values I want the issue is my viewmodel and view doesent seem to right, I get: "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[HomesProj.Models.UserRoleViewModel]'.

My Controller looks like this:

```
       public ActionResult Index()
      {
        var user = db.Users.ToList();

          ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
          var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new     RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));

            List<String> list = new List<String>();
           list.Add(user.ToString());
           list.Add(roleManager.ToString());


          return View(list);
          }
```

My Viewmodel looks like this:

```
      public class UserRoleViewModel
     {
      public ICollection<ApplicationUser> User { get; set; }

       public RoleManager<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }
      }
```

And my View like this:

```
     @model IEnumerable<HomesProj.Models.UserRoleViewModel>

     @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

      <h2>Index</h2>

      <p>
      @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
      </p>
      <table class="table">
      <tr>
      <th>
        @Html.DisplayName("Users")
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.DisplayName("Roles")
        </th>
          </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
        <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.User)
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.User)
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey         */            }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /*           id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
        </tr>
        }

       </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is right

You pass a list of strings:

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
return View(list);
```

but accept an enum

```
@model IEnumerable<HomesProj.Models.UserRoleViewModel>
```

presumably you intended to pass a list of UserRoleViewModel's?

Comment: Actually looking at the code it doesn't make much sense at all. I guess you should return an instance of UserRoleViewModel's, the view should also take one and the foreach should work on model.User, that'll get you started at least.